# How would you make this function work on any table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to break all the rules of databasing using the stuff function. I want to smush every applicable row into just one, for science, you know?

Problem is, I have to write a new function every time. They look like this:

```
    ALTER function [dbo].[stuffMeds](@VisitID varchar(55))
    returns varchar(max)

    as
    begin
    declare @string varchar(max)

    set @string = (select stuff( (
    select  distinct top 500 ', ' + DataItemID  from 
    EmrAcctPha_Medication med
    where 
    VisitID = @VisitID
    order by ', ' +  DataItemID desc
    for xml path ('')),1,2,'')
     )

    return @string

    end
```

used in a query like this:

```
    select AdmitDateTime, RoomID, dbo.stuffMeds(VisitID)
    from AbstractData
```

It turns a list like this:

Albuterol Sulfate
Amlodipine Besylate
Aspirin
Benztropine Mesylate
Bisacodyl
Ciprofloxacin
Collagenase
Divalproex Sodium
...

into a string like this:

Divalproex Sodium, Collagenase, Ciprofloxacin, Bisacodyl, Benztropine Mesylate, Aspirin, Amlodipine Besylate, Albuterol Sulfate

I can write it as a dynamic stored procedure, but you can't call sp_executesql from a function (or at least, I don't know how).

**Question** How would you write this function in a way that it could be used on any table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In another answer, @SQLRaptor makes the suggestion of using STRING_AGG. Working with that, it seems like the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT  AdmitDateTime, RoomID, med.stuffMeds
FROM    AbstractData AD
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  STRING_AGG(DataItemID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DataItemID ASC) stuffMeds
    FROM    EmrAcctPha_Medication med
    WHERE   AD.VisitID = med.VisitID
) med
```

Comment: huh, i've never seen something like that. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You have a built in function in SQL Server for this called STRING_AGG.
Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: my group by is going to be *humongous*. I'll play with string_agg for a bit. Maybe i'll use a bunch of CTE's to keep the grouping simpler.

Comment: @James it is very likely that the STRING_AGG will perform way better than the XML PATH approach you used originally. Let us know what you find.

Answer (score 1):

If we're breaking the rules and doing this for science...how about.

Create a View that Unions together the required columns from all the tables you are interested in and have a column that includes the source table name i.e. EmrAcctPha_Medication.

Then pass in the tablename to the function as a variable, and filter on @tablename & @visited.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[stuffMeds](@VisitID varchar(55),@tablename varchar(255))
returns varchar(max)

as
begin
declare @string varchar(max)

set @string = (select stuff( (
select  distinct top 500 ', ' + DataItemID  from 
dbo.myreallybigview med
where 
VisitID = @VisitID
AND
TableName = @tablename
order by ', ' +  DataItemID desc
for xml path ('')),1,2,'')
 )

return @string

end
```

Comment: what could possibly go wrong? I love it.

Comment: @James You are kidding, right?

Comment: lol yes. Lots could go wrong. I won't implement it. I still like it.

Comment: @James it seems dangerous is the middle name of this hospital, keeping medications in different tables for each ward/department will eventually kill a patient who moves between wards.

Comment: @pacreely where did you get the idea that we do that?

Comment: @James I'm guessing that emr is the E.R. plus Visitid is heavily used in clinical systems for patient admissions.

Comment: yep. and what part of that leads you to think that medication lists don't transfer with the patient?

Comment: @James I spent 11 years working deeply with Allscript's systems, you can never trust clinicians with data quality. They care more about treating the patient than IT systems.